# I'm having issues saving the file

Tags: command-line

In ~/.bash_profile, beneath the greeting you created, type

alias pd="pwd"

Save the file.

Press Enter to write the filename

Exit nano.

Clear the terminal window.

Comment: Quat is the question?

Comment: The "question" isn't clear, but I'm going to take a stab at it below anyway.

Comment: what's the issue you are having?

Comment: It appears you are unsure of whether you have actually saved the file. I agree with @CharlieHills that you likely did save the file correctly and are under the false notion that its contents will be re-sourced in the current shell instance automatically, which is not the case; this file is sourced when you initially launch the shell.  Either launch a new shell or source the file as answered below.

Comment: #homeworkLife #integrity #honor #yolo

Answer (score 2):

If I were to venture a guess, you're trying to define an alias and after editing .bash_profile the alias is not immediately taking effect.

If this is the case, try logging out and logging back in. Or execute the file immediately like so:

`$ . ~/.bash_profile`

Note the dot, the space, and then the file name. If all is well you can type "pd" to view your working directory. (That said, I'm not sure "pd" is much of a savings over "pwd", but perhaps that was just an example.)